# Writing output of a large dataset in excel in Python Pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

I have the following code snippet that helps me write my output in an excel file. This piece of code works fine if the dataset is not that big(for example, upto 100K records).

But this code doesnot work very well if my dataset is pretty big such as 10 million records.

So, in such case how can I 
Split the dataset into several smaller datasets and at the same time upload them all in one file. The target is to 
get all the data in one file.

```
import time


class WriteToExcel(object):

    def generate_report(self, output_data):
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        file_path = '/some/path/'
        file_name = 'file' + '_' + timestr + '.xlsx'

        try:
                        output_data.to_excel(file_path+file_name, index=False)
                        print("File generated named " + file_name + " at the location " + file_path)


        except IOError:
               print("Opps, I think file path is incorrect.")



## how to invoke the method
nis = WriteToExcel()
nis.generate_report(some_data)
```

Comment: Write the data to a single csv file?  It's not much use to create a 10million record Excel file unless you *really* need that format for some reason.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, need to write the data in a single csv file. any suggestion to improve the above code ?

Comment: I'm not a Python person, but it seems like you'd need different code to write a CSV file?

Comment: `output_data.to_csv(file_path+file_name, index=False)`? I believe excel has ~1 million limit in row count. [What is the maximum allowed rows in a Microsoft Excel .xls or .xlsx](https://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx)

Comment: @gyoza thanks a lot. this is the perfect solution I was looking for. appreciate it.

Comment: @gyoza so, I was able to save the dataset in a csv file. But got another issue that the data format(I mean datatypes) was changed in the new csv file while saving the data.
For example, I wanted to save a column in str format but it has changed to int64. Do you have any suggestion how to avoid such data format changing while saving data in csv?

Comment: @Ariful Haque I summarized my thoughts in Answer space, hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just re-write the solution I wrote in comment here just as a record.

```
output_data.to_csv(file_path+file_name, index=False)
```

As a side note, if you want to designate `dtypes` of each column when you re-read the csv from where you saved it, manually set `dtype` argument when you use `pd.read_csv`. Below is short example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame().assign(a=range(3), b=list('abc'))
df.a = df.a.astype(str)
df.to_csv(filepath, index=False)

# str --> int conversion happens here, so manually prevent it if you want
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype={'a': str})

>>> df2.dtypes
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
```

`pandas` infers `dtype` for each column when they are not specified, so if you need to keep `str` format when all the values look `int` from `pandas`, you need to manually set it when it is read.

Hope this helps.